# Unable to compile / run run book-examples in eclipse

Tags: vaadin

I am  trying to run [sample code "MyHierarchicalUI" from section 4.2](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/application.architecture.html)  from "book of vaadin" and this code refers to `TreeExample` and `TableExample` classes which can be found at

[http://dev.vaadin.com/svn/doc/book-examples](http://dev.vaadin.com/svn/doc/book-examples/)/

I downloaded the book example code from mentioned svn link and imported it as existing eclipse project,however when I try to compile / run this project in eclipse I get the following error.

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Integrated External Tool Builder' on project 'book-examples'.
The file does not exist for the external tool named Copy sources.
The file does not exist for the external tool named Copy sources.
```

Answer (score 0):

`book-examples` project is not valid `vaadin` project so can not be imported directly, we can not  build it directly as vaadin project due to missing artifacts like `ivy.xml` and `ivysettings.xml`.

To use any code from book-examples project you will have to bring the code to your project manually (copy/paste), however a support ticker to make  `book-example` project import-able / build-able and run-able has been created and can be tracked using this link  [Ticket # `13078`](http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/13078).